# What is the relationship between harmonic analysis and probability, if any?

Tags: probability-distributions, fourier-analysis

$e^{(ix)^2} = e^{-x^2} = e^{z^2} $

$i^2 = \sqrt{-1}$

$ \frac{dz^2}{dz} = 2z $

$ e^{2ix} $ is foundation of Fourier Transform whereas $e^{-x^2} $ is basis for normal probability density function. When looking above it's very strange to see this simple exponent manipulation connects both.

What papers should I look for to learn more about connection between Fourier analysis and normal distribution? Can harmonics in Fourier analysis be actually seen as form of statistical parameters like deviation for example?

Comment: Well, Fourier analysis isn't really 'founded on' $e^{2ix}.$ More usually, $e^{ix}$ or $e^{2\pi i x}.$ So the derivative thing isn't that interesting.

Comment: You'll probably find this interesting: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)
The characteristic function of a random variable is essentially the Fourier transform. It is also used in an elegant proof of some version of the central limit theorem.